# Building python3 with ROS using vison_opencv: Raise CvBridgeError, "encoding specified as %s but image has incompatible type %s" % (encoding,cv_type)

Tags: python-3.x, ros, python-2.x, vision

I am trying to run python3 with ROS. By default ROS melodic is installed with python2.7.
Hence I have installed the python3 using following instructions:

https://dkqhzm2.tistory.com/entry/ImportError-dynamic-module-does-not-define-module-export-function-PyInitcvbridgeboost-in-Xavier-AGX

where I have cloned the cv_bridge src from the following git: which is called vision_opencv
https://github.com/mikejmills/vision_opencv

I also put in my scripts as

> #!/usr/bin/env python3

So that it complies in python3 when I did catkin_make

The following error is the trouble with this package:

```
rrcam@rrcam20220901-001:~/catkin_ws$ rosrun camera_calibration cameracalibrator.py --size 12x8 --square 0.05 image:=/cam1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/rrcam/catkin_ws/src/camera_calibration/nodes/cameracalibrator.py", line 39, in <module>
    from camera_calibration.camera_calibrator import OpenCVCalibrationNode
  File "/home/rrcam/catkin_ws/src/camera_calibration/src/camera_calibration/camera_calibrator.py", line 44, in <module>
    from camera_calibration.calibrator import MonoCalibrator, StereoCalibrator, Patterns
  File "/home/rrcam/catkin_ws/src/camera_calibration/src/camera_calibration/calibrator.py", line 38, in <module>
    import cv_bridge
  File "/home/rrcam/catkin_ws/devel/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cv_bridge/__init__.py", line 34, in <module>
    exec(__fh.read())
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/rrcam/catkin_ws/src/vision_opencv/cv_bridge/python/cv_bridge/core.py", line 164
    raise CvBridgeError, "encoding specified as %s, but image has incompatible type %s" % (encoding, cv_type)
                          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Not sure what to do.

If I compile only with python2.7 instead of python3 I get error as:

```
rrcam@rrcam20220901-001:~/catkin_ws$ rosrun camera_calibration cameracalibrator.py --size 12x8 --square 0.05 image:=/cam1
Exception in thread Thread-6:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 801, in __bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/home/rrcam/catkin_ws/src/camera_calibration/src/camera_calibration/camera_calibrator.py", line 118, in run
    self.function(m)
  File "/home/rrcam/catkin_ws/src/camera_calibration/src/camera_calibration/camera_calibrator.py", line 242, in handle_monocular
    max_chessboard_speed = self._max_chessboard_speed)
  File "/home/rrcam/catkin_ws/src/camera_calibration/src/camera_calibration/calibrator.py", line 954, in __init__
    super(MonoCalibrator, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
TypeError: super() argument 1 must be type, not classobj
```

Can someone tell me how to tackle this problem?

Comment: that, `raise CvBridgeError, "encoding...`, is python 2.x code. you can't mix 2.x and 3.x code. or libraries. -- file a bug with the authors of the project. this is not a suitable question for SO

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz it’s honestly not even a bug. OP is using a version of ROS that is built for 2.x, thus the openCV version it uses is also for 2.x.

Answer (score 1):

You’re trying to use Python2.x code with Python3, which doesn’t work. If you want to use Python3 with ROS you shouldn’t be using Melodic, since it targets 2.x. You can get it to *sort of* work with Python3, but it’s still not a great idea.

If you want Python3 you should be using the Noetic distro.

Comment: I tried using python2.7, but the project seems to be using python version 3. 

[http://wiki.ros.org/camera_calibration](This is the project )

`https://github.com/ros-perception/image_pipeline/tree/aa6437b1979662c258e21ed1362e2038a4f9f590/camera_calibration`

The above is the project link git.
`Hence  I am getting the compile error as above. The Jetson Xavier I have is compatible with Ubuntu 18.0.4 ,i.e. ROS Melodic.` 
I am not sure what to do?

Comment: @NagarjunVinukonda did it install via apt or from source? Because that package explicitly states that it supports Melodic and looking at the repo it appears to be in Python2

Comment: You mean the vision_opencv pakage? I have installed it from the source git as followed using the instructions in the link provided above:
https://dkqhzm2.tistory.com/entry/ImportError-dynamic-module-does-not-define-module-export-function-PyInitcvbridgeboost-in-Xavier-AGX

Comment: @NagarjunVinukonda I mean the camera_calibration package you linked that’s producing errors. If you installed it via git you need to make sure you check out the right branch for your ros distro. i.e. `git checkout melodic`

Comment: Thank you. You are right. I am developing the code in Noetic version and testing that package in melodic version which is providing me the conflicts. I downloaded the melodic version and it is working, thanks.

Comment: "@BTables" Also this is very silly of me. Would you recommend to delete this question?

Comment: @NagarjunVinukonda not at all, this is actually a fairly common mistake that a lot of people make. If you think my answer was sufficient I’d mark it as correct, because it’s likely this could help someone in the future.